# before_save & before_create titleize trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a rails app and I am trying to titleize an attribute before it is saved or created. I am pretty sure I have done this correctly, however, whenever I try to create a new record in my rails console, the titleize is not taking place. Here is my model code:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :region_id

  belongs_to :region

  before_save :tileize_name
  before_create :tileize_name


  def tileize_name
    self.name.titleize
  end

end
```

When I read an attribute in my console, the titleize method works. For example:

```
Region.find(4).name
 => "arizona" 


Region.find(4).name.titleize
 => "Arizona"
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Using before_save and before_create is pointless - before_save callbacks get called on create and update

Answer (score 7):

You're titleizing the name but not saving it.

```
string = "hello"
string.titleize
# => "Hello"
string
# => "hello"

string = string.titleize
# => "Hello"
string
# => "Hello"
```

You need to assign the titleized name to your name attribute.

```
def tileize_name
  self.name = self.name.titleize
end
```

Comment: @flyingarmadillo Correct answer. Accept-worthy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually adding

`before_save { self.chefname = chefname.titleize }`

in "your_model.rb" would solve this problem.

so it would look like

```
class Chef < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.chefname = chefname.titleize }
end
```

Also it's worth taking a look at https://github.com/granth/titleize

Answer (score -1):

Or you can do this,

```
before_save { self.name.titleize! }
```

The bag operator changes and saves the value. Then you won't need **before_create**.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method 'titleize!' for "test string":String` Not sure if this a recent removal from Rails 4 but if it doesn't work any more, I have to mark you down (sorry).

Comment: `titleize!` is not a method

Comment: note: this pattern of using `!` at the end of a string manipulation method in order to return the modified result does hold true for most other methods, like `upcase`, `upcase!`